# Summation of function in a for loop (matlab)

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop, sum

Suppose I have a function `f(x) = cos(x)`. I want to evaluate `f(x)` in a form of `g(x) = 1/2*f(0) + sum(1/4*f(a+h*i)) (for i is odd) + sum(3/4*f(a+h*i)) (for i is even except 0 and 10) + 1/2*f(b)`

I write the code below, but it did not give the sum of `(1/4*f(a+h*i)(for i is odd)` and the sum of `3/4*f(a+h*i)(for i is even except 0 and 10)`.

```
a=0
h=0.1571
n=10
b=1.5708
for i = 1: n
    simp_int2 = 0;
    simp_int3 = 0;
    simp_int1 = 1/2*f(0)
    if i < n
        if rem(i,2)~=0
            simp_int2 = simp_int2 + 1/4*f(a+h*i)
        end
        if rem(i,2)==0
            simp_int3 = simp_int3 + 3/4*f(a+h*i)
        end
    end
    simp_int4 = 1/2*f(b)
end
simp_int = simp_int1 + simp_int2 + simp_int3 + simp_int4
```

I also tried cumsum and symsum. Both not working the way I intended. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Also, if you have a function in vectorized form (which `cos(x)` is) you can just use vector values for your inputs and sum the results thus doing this task in a single line of code: `1/2*f(0) + sum(1/4*f(a + h*[1:2:n])) + sum(3/4*f(a+h*[2:2:n-1])) + 1/2*f(b)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting the accumulation variables at every iteration.  Move the `simp_*` initializations to outside of the `for` loop.

Specifically:

```
a=0
h=0.1571
n=10
b=1.5708
% Change
simp_int1 = 1/2*f(0);
simp_int2 = 0;
simp_int3 = 0;        
simp_int4 = 1/2*f(b);
for i = 1: n
    if i < n
        if rem(i,2)~=0
            simp_int2 = simp_int2 + 1/4*f(a+h*i)
        end
        if rem(i,2)==0
            simp_int3 = simp_int3 + 3/4*f(a+h*i)
        end
    end
end
simp_int = simp_int1 + simp_int2 + simp_int3 + simp_int4;
```

Comment: @Orangeblue haha no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Since your function will return vector output for vector input you can do this without a for loop:

```
a=0
h=0.1571
n=10
b=1.5708
simp_int = 1/2*f(0) + sum(1/4*f(a + h*[1:2:n])) + sum(3/4*f(a+h*[2:2:n-1])) + 1/2*f(b)
```

Comment: Thanks! Rayryeng helped me find the problem!